# IF and AND statements within Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, if

I'm a Visualforce newbie so forgive me if my question comes across as a bit ignorant...

I'm trying to render a Visualforce page based on specific conditions. I got it to work with one condition but when I add conditions to the statement, it doesn't work.

Something like this works:

```
<apex:outputpanel rendered="{!IF(Opportunity.StageName == 'Closed Won', true, false)}"></apex:outputpanel>
```

Something like this doesn't work:

```
<apex:outputpanel rendered="{!IF(Opportunity.StageName =='Closed Won' && Opportunity.Approval_Status__c != 'Approved', true, false)}"</apex:outputpanel>
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should work, to be honest, but realistically, you don't need the IF statement--a Boolean value is already a Boolean value, so you don't need another Boolean value.

```
rendered="{!AND(Opportunity.StageName='Closed Won', Opportunity.Approval_Status__c!='Approved')}"
```

Sometimes the `&` has a problem, since Visualforce is technically XML, so using `AND` can help prevent this problem.

Comment: Amazing! Using the !AND worked perfectly.